# Looping through JSON result of AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue object

Tags: asp.net, json

My webservice returns objects formatted based on the asp.net AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDownNameValue object.

How do I loop through this JSON result and select the value of property "name"?
So: Drenthe, Flevoland, Friesland etc
[{"isDefaultValue":false,"name":"Drenthe","optionTitle":null,"value":"1"},{"isDefaultValue":false,"name":"Flevoland","optionTitle":null,"value":"16"},{"isDefaultValue":false,"name":"Friesland","optionTitle":null,"value":"2"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

(...)

```
success: function (response) { LoadData(response.d); }
```

(...)

```
function LoadData(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var vname;
            vname = data[i].name;
            //use vname from here

        }
    }
```

Hope that helps.